# Setting text on DataGridViewButtonColumn - bug?

Tags: c#

I am trying to set the text of a `DataGridViewButtonColumn` in Visual Studio 2013 Update 1 and failing miserably.

I took the example from here which doesn't work. It creates the button but no text is visible:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn.text(v=vs.110).aspx

The only way I have found of setting the text on the button is by modifying the cell's `Value` property, which is definitely not what I'm after.

Am I missing something or is this a bug with Visual Studio 2013 or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button will be blank if there isn't a data row. The "Add Row" row doesn't count. So add a row to your grid, and then the Button should have the Text field appear on the button.

If you are looking to have the button in the "Add Row" column not be blank, try using the CellFormatting event to set the value:

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, 
                                  DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e) {
  if (e.RowIndex == dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1) {
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1) {  // Your Button Column
      e.Value = "Add Row";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What if the button is a browse button which is there exactly for the purpose of of adding data via the "Add Row" row?

Comment: @cogumel0 How would that work?  If you have 10 rows, you want every button to say "Add Row"?  Your statement `The only way I have found of setting the text on the button is by modifying the cell's Value property, which is definitely not what I'm after.` doesn't make a lot of sense.  What are you after?

Comment: no, the buttons say browse. The button allows you select a file to be converted into a BLOB and inserted into the DB. The datagridview displays all existing rows on the database and allows for new rows to be added. Both new rows and existing rows should contain the browse button. On new rows you can browse and select a file to convert to BLOB, on existing rows you can replace the file that's associated with that row by another file, which is why the browse button still applies.

Comment: @cogumel0 ok, change my code from `e.Value = "Add Row";` to `e.Value = "Browse";`